# Select data from select box data will show next multiselect checkbox

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu

I am using react js as frontend and springboot as a backend, code working fine but when i select company name from select company dropdown data will show in next multiselect box. But when i select data select all then it will select 2 or 3 properties only and if i select manually data will selected even or odd format like if select 2 then data will selected 4 or 6 or if i selected 1 then data will be selected 1 ,3 5. Another problem is when data submitted data documentId also stored inside my json as string format and when select top to down data no chnages but if select down to top then data will orverlap. How to avoid it. I am newbie in react js.

AddCandidate.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import "../components/myapp.css";
import { API_BASE_URL, API_BASE_URL_COMPANY } from '../env';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const CandidateRegister = () => {
    const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
    const [selectedCompany, setSelectedCompany] = useState('');
    const [candidateName, setCandidateName] = useState('');
    const [offerDate, setOfferDate] = useState('');
    const [dateOfJoining, setDateOfJoining] = useState('');
    const [jobTitle, setJobTitle] = useState('');
    const [employeeCode, setEmployeeCode] = useState('');
    const [fixedSalary, setFixedSalary] = useState('');
    const [totalGrossSalary, setTotalGrossSalary] = useState('');
    const [basicDA, setBasicDA] = useState('');
    const [hra, setHra] = useState('');
    const [specialAllowances, setSpecialAllowances] = useState('');
    const [performanceBonus] = useState('50000');
    const [finalFixedSalary, setFinalFixedSalary] = useState('');
    const [selectedDocumentTypes, setSelectedDocumentTypes] = useState([]);
    const [documentOptions, setDocumentOptions] = useState([]);
    const [selectAllDocuments, setSelectAllDocuments] = useState(false);

    const calculate = () => {
        const salary = parseInt(fixedSalary.replace(/,/g, ''), 10);
        const basicDAValue = Math.round(salary * 0.4565);
        const hraValue = Math.round(salary * 0.1826);
        const specialAllowancesValue = Math.round(salary * 0.3608);
        const finalSalary = basicDAValue + hraValue + specialAllowancesValue;
        const totalGross = finalSalary + parseInt(performanceBonus.replace(), 10);
        setBasicDA(basicDAValue);
        setHra(hraValue);
        setSpecialAllowances(specialAllowancesValue);
        setTotalGrossSalary(totalGross);
        setFinalFixedSalary(finalSalary);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCompanies();
    }, []);

    const fetchCompanies = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(API_BASE_URL_COMPANY + '/list');
            setCompanies(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching companies:', error);
        }
    };

    const handleCompanyChange = async (e) => {
        setSelectedCompany(e.target.value);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (selectedCompany) {
            fetchDocuments(selectedCompany);
        }
    }, [selectedCompany]);

    const fetchDocuments = async (companyId) => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${API_BASE_URL_COMPANY}/${companyId}`);
            if (response.data && response.data.documents) {
                const documents = response.data.documents[0];
                const documentOptions = Object.entries(documents).map(([key, value]) => ({ label: getDocumentName(key), value }));
                setSelectedDocumentTypes([]);
                setDocumentOptions(documentOptions);
                setSelectedDocumentTypes([]);
                setSelectAllDocuments(false);
            } else {
                console.error('Invalid response : documents not found');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching documents:', error);
        }
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!selectedCompany) {
            alert('Please select a company.');
            return;
        }
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(API_BASE_URL + '/add', {
                candidateName,
                selectedCompany,
                offerDate,
                dateOfJoining,
                jobTitle,
                employeeCode,
                fixedSalary,
                totalGrossSalary,
                basicDA,
                hra,
                specialAllowances,
                performanceBonus,
                finalFixedSalary,
                selectedDocumentTypes
            });
            console.log(response.data);
            clearForm();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    };

    const clearForm = () => {
        setCandidateName('');
        setSelectedCompany('');
        setOfferDate('');
        setDateOfJoining('');
        setJobTitle('');
        setEmployeeCode('');
        setFixedSalary('');
        setTotalGrossSalary('');
        setBasicDA('');
        setHra('');
        setSpecialAllowances('');
        setFinalFixedSalary('');
        setSelectedDocumentTypes([]);
        setDocumentOptions([]);
    };

    // const toggleSelectAllDocuments = (e) => {
    //     setSelectAllDocuments(e.target.checked);
    //     if (e.target.checked) {
    //         // Select only specific document options when "Select All" is checked
    //         const selectedOptions = documentOptions
    //             .filter(option => {
    //                 // Exclude 'documentId' from selection
    //                 return option.value !== 'documentId';
    //             })
    //             .map(option => option.value);
    //         setSelectedDocumentTypes(selectedOptions);
    //     } else {
    //         setSelectedDocumentTypes([]);
    //     }
    // };

    const toggleSelectAllDocuments = (e) => {
        setSelectAllDocuments(e.target.checked);
        if (e.target.checked) {
          const filteredDocumentOptions = documentOptions.filter((option) => option.value !== 'documentId');
          setSelectedDocumentTypes(filteredDocumentOptions.map((option) => option.value));
        } else {
          setSelectedDocumentTypes([]);
        }
      };

    // const handleDocumentChange = (e) => {
    //     const documentType = e.target.value;
    //     const isChecked = e.target.checked;

    //     if (documentType === 'documentId' && !isChecked) {
    //         return;
    //     }

    //     if (isChecked) {
    //         // Add the selected document type if it's not already selected
    //         setSelectedDocumentTypes(prevSelected => {
    //             if (!prevSelected.includes(documentType)) {
    //                 return [...prevSelected, documentType];
    //             }
    //             return prevSelected;
    //         });
    //     } else {
    //         // Remove the deselected document type
    //         setSelectedDocumentTypes(prevSelected => prevSelected.filter(item => item !== documentType));
    //     }
    // };

    const handleDocumentChange = (e) => {
        const documentType = e.target.value;
        const isChecked = e.target.checked;
    
        if (documentType === 'documentId' && !isChecked) {
            return;
        }
    
        if (isChecked) {
            // Add the selected document type if it's not already selected
            setSelectedDocumentTypes(prevSelected => {
                if (!prevSelected.includes(documentType)) {
                    return [...prevSelected, documentType];
                }
                return prevSelected;
            });
        } else {
            // Remove the deselected document type
            setSelectedDocumentTypes(prevSelected => prevSelected.filter(item => item !== documentType));
        }
    };
    const getDocumentName = (documentKey) => {
        const documentNameMapping = {
            experienceLetterUrl: 'Experience',
            relievingLetterUrl: 'Relieving',
            offerLetterUrl: 'Offer Letter',
            salarySlipUrl: 'Salary Slip',
            incrementLetterUrl: 'Increment',
            apparisalLetterUrl: 'Appraisal',
        };
        return documentNameMapping[documentKey] || documentKey;
    };


    return (
        <>
            <div className='card'>
                <div className='card-header'>
                    <h4 className='card-title text-center'>Candidate Register</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="card card-properties">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="container-fluid">
                           

                        <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="candidateName">Candidate Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="candidateName" name="candidateName" value={candidateName} onChange={(e) => setCandidateName(e.target.value)} required />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="company" className="form-label">Select Company</label>
                                        <select
                                            className="form-control"
                                            id="company"
                                            name="company"
                                            value={selectedCompany}
                                            onChange={handleCompanyChange}
                                            required
                                        >
                                            <option value="">Select Company</option>
                                            {companies.map(company => (
                                                <option key={company.companyId} value={company.companyId}>{company.companyName}</option>
                                            ))}
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="offerDate" className="form-label">Offer Date</label>
                                        <input type="date" className="form-control" id="offerDate" name="offerDate" value={offerDate} onChange={(e) => setOfferDate(e.target.value)} required />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="dateOfJoining" className="form-label">Date of Joining:</label>
                                        <input type="date" className="form-control" id="dateOfJoining" name="setDateOfJoining" value={dateOfJoining} onChange={(e) => setDateOfJoining(e.target.value)} required />

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-6">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="jobTitle" className="form-label">Job Title</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="jobTitle" name="jobTitle" value={jobTitle} onChange={(e) => setJobTitle(e.target.value)} required />

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-3">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="employeeCode" className="form-label">Employee Code</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="employeeCode" name="employeeCode" value={employeeCode} onChange={(e) => setEmployeeCode(e.target.value)} required />

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-3">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="fixedSalary" className="form-label">Fixed Salary:</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="fixedSalary" value={fixedSalary} onChange={(e) => setFixedSalary(e.target.value)} onBlur={calculate} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="totalGrossSalary" className="form-label">Total Gross Salary</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="totalGrossSalary" value={totalGrossSalary} readOnly />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="basicDA" className="form-label">Basic + DA</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="basicDA" value={basicDA} readOnly />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="hra" className="form-label">HRA</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="hra" value={hra} readOnly />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="specialAllowances" className="form-label">Special Allowances:</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="specialAllowances" value={specialAllowances} readOnly />

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="performanceBonus" className="form-label">Performance Bonus</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="performanceBonus" value={performanceBonus} readOnly />

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="col-md-4">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="finalFixedSalary" className="form-label">Final Fixed Salary</label>
                                        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="finalFixedSalary" value={finalFixedSalary} readOnly />

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>


                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-2">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <input
                                            type="checkbox"
                                            id="selectAllDocuments"
                                            checked={selectAllDocuments}
                                            onChange={toggleSelectAllDocuments}
                                        />
                                        <label htmlFor="selectAllDocuments">Select All</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-md-10">
                                    {documentOptions.map(option => (
                                        <div key={option.value} className="form-check">
                                            <input
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                id={option.value}
                                                value={option.value}
                                                checked={selectedDocumentTypes.includes(option.value)}
                                                onChange={handleDocumentChange}
                                                className="form-check-input"
                                            />
                                            <label htmlFor={option.value} className="form-check-label">{option.label}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    ))}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                <Link to={'/candidateList'}>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary ml-2">View</button>
                                </Link>
                                <Link to={'/companyList'}>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary ml-2">Company</button>
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default CandidateRegister;
```

Here my Json

```
basicDA: 472773
​
candidateName: "Jhon"
​
certificateId: 9
​
dateOfJoining: "2024-03-27"
​
employeeCode: "Jhon4563"
​
finalFixedSalary: 1035543
​
fixedSalary: 1035647
​
hra: 189109
​
jobTitle: "Senior Java Fullstack Developer"
​
offerDate: "2024-03-13"
​
performanceBonus: 50000
​
selectedCompany: "star technology"
​
selectedDocumentTypes: Array(7) [ "1", "1VOlmb2_jlkjklj-a1RhCWvjf0ww", "kjhjkhkjhkjhkj_-wG76Cjktf0", … ]
​​
0: "1"
​​
1: "1VOlmb2_ssssjlkjlk-a1RhCWvjf0ww"
​​
2: ",n,mn,mn,mniiopipoipo_-wG76Cjktf0"
​​
3: "1VOlmb2_uuutsygf-a1RhCWvjf0ww"
​​
4: "1VOlmb2_optueej-a1RhCWvjf0ww"
​​
5: "rtweqohsngc_-wG76Cjktf0"
​​
6: "jjdjporyeu_-wG76Cjktf0"
​​
length: 7
​
specialAllowances: 373661
​
totalGrossSalary: 1085543
```

I tried all apporch but no luck